# Operator precedence C++

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Could someone please explain the operator precedence that takes place in the following C++ statement?

`int lower = height[height[l] < height[r] ? l++ : r--];`

Assume, `height=[0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]` and `int l = 0, r = height.size()-1;`.
As per my understanding, `height[l] < height[r]?` would be evaluated first, followed by `l++` or `r--` as the case might be (`l++` in this case).  Then the value of `height[updated l]` should be assigned to `lower`.  Thus `lower` should be `1`; but the output says it is `0`.  How?  What would be the correct order of the evaluation of the statements then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `l++` uses the post-increment operator. The value of l is increased after the value of the expression is evaluated. So, when l is 0, the value of `l++` is 0 and not 1, even though the variable l will have the value 1 afterwards.

Using `++l` would show a different behaviour.

The following statement in the question is incorrect:

> Then the value of height[updated l] should be assigned to lower

The updated value of l is not used as the array index, but the value of the expression `l++`, which is the value of l before it is increased.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please let me know the total order of evaluation of the statement `int lower = height[height[l] < height[r] ? l++ : r--];`?

Comment: @user6490375 The order is as you stated, but you got the increment incorrect.

Comment: Note that the value of `l++` isn't determined by operator precedence. It is simply defined to be so.

Answer (score 1):

`l++` is the post increment operator, which means it will be incremented after the operation is complete. Hence the output `0`, everything else is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Code is equal to:

```
int lower = height[height[l] < height[r] ? l : r];
(height[l] < height[r]) ? l+=1 : r-=1;
```